# Javascript Test case is not passing even though code is right

Tags: javascript, html, debugging, testng

my code is not passing test cases what should I do..... so I have written this code and it is not passing test cases and showing that expected type of int. Even though it works perfectly in my browser according to the question asked.

```
<body>

<button type="submit" onclick="callMe()">show</button>

<script>
    
function callMe() {
    
    let Passenger = {
        Name: "Arun",
        Age: 28,
        reservedStatus: true
    }

    document.write("<div id='name'>Name:" + Passenger.Name + "</div>");
    document.write("<div id='age'>Age: " + parseInt(Passenger.Age) + "</div>");
    document.write("<div id='reservedStatus'>Reservation Status: " + Passenger.reservedStatus + "</div>");
}
</script>
```

[question image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sh4TS.jpg)

Testing File index.test.js

```js
describe('DataType', function() {
    let document;
    beforeAll(function() {
      document = getDOM();
    });

    describe('DataTypeValidaton', function() {
      it('checking name', function() {
      callMe();
      var varName = document.getElementById("name").innerHTML;
      expect(varName).toBe("Arun");
    });

    it('checking age', function() {
      var varAge = document.getElementById("age").innerHTML;
      //expect(varAge).toBe('28');
      expect(parseInt(varAge)).toEqual(28);
    });

    it('Checking reservation status', function() {
      var varRS = document.getElementById("reservedStatus").innerHTML;
      //var c=((varAge==true || varAge==false))?true:false;
      expect(varRS=='true').toBe(true);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if `reservedStatus` element contains `true` as a string, you can do something like:

```
expect(varRS.includes('true')).toBe(true);
```

Comment: You are doing in the last test case `varRS == 'true'`, should be `varRS === 'true'` for a full and great comparation. But your `varRS` actually contains `'Reservation Status: true'`. So try to modify your expect to `expect(varRS.includes('true')).toBe(true)` or `expect(varRS).toEqual('Reservation Status: true')`

Answer (score 0):

so guys i got the answer after 5 days the question posted by hackerrank was wrong and it expected only

```
<div id="name">Passenger.Name</div>
```

instead of

```
<div id="name">Name: Passenger.Name</div>
```

Comment: Highly doubt how anyones answer was wrong if the `id` on element didnt change. Maybe you just prefer not to give attribution?